# Using find to exclude a directory and tar up everything else in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, find

I have following in a directory:

dir1
dir2
file1
file2

I want to tar up everything except dir1

When I do:

```
find . -path '*dir1*' -prune -o -print
```

I don't see dir1 in the output ( as expected)

But when I do:

```
find . -path '*dir1*' -prune -o -exec tar -czvf documents.tgz  '{}' \+
```

I see that dir1 also gets tarred up in documents.tgz. Why ?

Comment: You could just use `*` instead of `.` to exclude the current working directory.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the `.` in the output. `.` also gets `tar`ed.

Use this intead, it will exclude both; `.` and `dir1`:

```
find . -not -path '*dir1*' -not -path "." -exec tar -czvf documents.tgz  '{}' \+
```

See the contents of `documents.tgz`:

```
$ tar tf documents.tgz
./file2
./file1
./dir2/
```

Answer (score 1):

tar also has an "exclude" option you can add one or more times.

For example:

```
tar czvf documents.tgz --exlude dir1 --exclude dir2 *
```

Note: I would rather create the tar in a different directory, to avoid including documents.tgz itself in tar in case you run the command another time without deleting it in the meantime.